# VsCode PHP-Intellisense using composer and autoload.php

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intellisense, autoload

I am using composer for dependency-management in a new **Php**-Project.

I plan to just use the **autoload.php** of **composer** to include/require the **external libraries**.

My problem is, that **VsCode** isn't able to recognize which files would get included via the autoload, and so it doesn't provide me with any **intellisense/code-completion**-features related to the libraries.

Does anybody have a solution/workaround for this problem, that would give me the desired features?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

okay, right after posting my question, i found a simple solution, in form of an extension.
It is called **intelephense**. You might want to take a look at it in the **marketplace**:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client

Comment: Does not solve problem

Comment: Restarting vscode after installing a composer package worked.